# Vectorising 5 nested FOR loops

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, nested-loops, dft

I am writing a program in MATLAB as a part of my project based on DFT.

Let the `N x N` data matrix be `X` and the corresponding DFT matrix be `Y`, then the DFT coefficients can be expressed as

```
 Y(k1,k2) = ∑(n1=0:N-1)∑(n2=0:N-1)[X(n1,n2)*(WN^(n1k1+n2k2))]               (1)

            0≤k1,k2≤N-1
            Where WN^k=e^((-j2πk)/N)
```

Since the twiddle factor WN is periodic, `(1)` can be expressed as

```
Y(k1,k2)=∑(n1=0:N-1)∑(n1=0:N-1)[X(n1,n2)*(WN^([(n1k1+n2k2)mod N) ]          (2)
```

The exponent `((n1k1 +n2k2)) N = p` is satisfied by a set of `(n1,n2)` for a given `(k1,k2)`. Hence, by grouping such data and applying the property that `WN^(p+N /2) = -(WN^P)`,

`(2)` can be expressed as

```
 Y(k1,k2)= ∑(p=0:M-1)[Y(k1,k2,p)*(WN^p)]                                    (3)
```

Where

```
 Y(k1,k2,p)= ∑(∀(n1,n2)|z=p)X(n1,n2) - ∑(∀(n1,n2)|z=p+M)X(n1,n2)           (4)

 z=[(n1k1+n2k2)mod N]                                                       (5)
```

I am coding a program to find `Y(k1,k2,p)`.ie I need to create slices of 2d matrices(ie a 3D matrix in which each slice is a 2D matrix )from a given 2D square matrix (which is the matrix `X`)..Dimensions of `X` can be upto 512.

Based on the above equations,I have written a code as follows.I need to vectorise it.

```
N=size(X,1);
M=N/2;
Y(1:N,1:N,1:M)=0;
for k1 = 1:N
for k2 = 1:N
   for p= 1:M
       for n1=1:N
           for n2=1:N
               N1=n1-1; N2=n2-1; P=p-1; K1=k1-1; K2=k2-1;
             z=mod((N1*K1+N2*K2),N); 
             if (z==P)                                       
               Y(k1,k2,p)= Y(k1,k2,p)+ X(n1,n2);
           elsif (z==(P+M))
               Y(k1,k2,p)= Y(k1,k2,p)- X(n1,n2);
            end
           end
       end
    end
   end
```

As there is 5 FOR loops, the execution time is very large for large dimensions of N. Hence please provide me a solution for eliminating the FOR loops and vectorising the code..I need to make the code execute in maximum speed...Thanks Again..

Comment: Please provide example input data, which size is `X`? And what is the `-->A` for?

Comment: Input X is a square matrix..size of X can be upto 512...--> A is used simply for denoting the condition.

Comment: The `-->` produces a syntax error. If there is any use, please fix the line and explain 'A'.

Comment: Do you want to do a mere DFT? Why not just use 'fft2'?

Comment: No.. I dont want to do DFT in a direct manner..I am formulating another method for calculating DFT by using layers of 2D matrices. Hence I need to obtain Y(k1,k2,p) only.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a first hint to vectorize the most inner loop.

From your code, we can notice that `n1`, `N1`, `P`, `K1` and `K2` are constant in this loop.
So we can rewrite `z` as a mask vector as follows:

```
z = mod(N1*K1+K2*(0:N-1));
```

Then your if-statement is equivalent to adding the sum of all elements in X so that `z==P` minus the sum of all elements in X so that `z==P+M`. Rewriting this is straightforward:

```
Y(k1,k2,p)= Y(k1,k2,p)+sum(X(n1,z==P))-sum(X(n1,z==P+M));
```

So your program can be first written as follows:

```
N=size(X,1);
M=N/2;
Y(1:N,1:N,1:M)=0;
for k1 = 1:N
  for k2 = 1:N
    for p= 1:M
      for n1=1:N
        N1=n1-1; P=p-1; K1=k1-1; K2=k2-1;
        z=mod(N1*K1+K2*(0:N-1),N); 
        Y(k1,k2,p) = sum(X(n1,z==P))-sum(X(n1,z==P+M));
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can do the same thing with `n1`; for that, you need to construct a 2D array for z, such as:

```
z = mod(K1*repmat(0:N-1,N,1)+K2*repmat((0:N-1).',1,N));
```

Notice that `size(z)==size(X)`.Then the 2D sum for Y becomes:

```
Y(k1,k2,p) = Y(k1,k2,p)+sum(X(z==P))-sum(X(z==P+M));
```

The `+=` operation is here no longer needed, since you access only once to each element of Y:

```
Y(k1,k2,p)= sum(X(n1,z==P))-sum(X(n1,z==P+M));
```

And so we discard one more loop:

```
N=size(X,1);
M=N/2;
Y(1:N,1:N,1:M)=0;
for k1 = 1:N
  for k2 = 1:N
    for p= 1:M
      P=p-1; K1=k1-1; K2=k2-1;
      z = mod(K1*repmat(0:N-1,N,1)+K2*repmat((0:N-1).',1,N)); 
      Y(k1,k2,p) = sum(X(z==P))-sum(X(z==P+M));
    end
  end
end
```

Concerning the other loops, I don't think it worths it to vectorize them, as you have to build a 5D array, which could be very huge in memory. My advise is to keep `z` as a 2D array, as it is of the size of X. If it does not fit well in memory, just vectorize the most inner loop.

Comment: Thanks for the solution...Please provide the way to vectorise the remaining 3 loops..I need to execute the program as fast as possible..Currently the time for processing  64x64 matrix is 20.9 seconds compared to the original code which takes up 28.7 seconds...I need to process higher order matrices upto the order 512..So please provide the solution for vectorising the remaining 3 loops...Thanks Again..

Comment: `Y(k1,k2,p) = Y(k1,k2,p)+sum(X(z==P))-sum(X(z==P+M));` could be replaced with `Y(k1,k2,p) = sum(X(z==P))-sum(X(z==P+M));`. Probably does not speed up the code, but makes it easier to read. Maybe it helps someone to find a vectorisation.

Comment: @DanielR Indeed! I edit my answer in this way, thanks for pointing that. I do think it can speed up the code a little ... it dépends on what Matlab is really doing in this case.

Comment: @VISHNUJMENON The key function for vectorizing such loops is `ndgrid`. You can use it to build all indexes in a once ... but it will take LOTS of memory: on my computer, Matlab throws out of memory for square matrices of order 512.

Comment: @Bentoy13..I managed to vectorise the `k1` and `k2` loops to get `z` as a 3d matrix where each layer corresponds to `z` obtained by your solution..Now how can I do the summing operation?..thanks again..

Comment: @VISHNUJMENON Can you post the resulting code please, to see how you compute z as a 3D matrix?

Comment: @Bentoy 13..`N=size(X,1);                                      M=N/2;                                                         c=N*N;                                                    N=size(X,1);X=repmat(X,[1,1,c])
q=zeros(N,N);w=zeros(N,N);t=zeros(1,1,c);r=zeros(1,1,c);z=zeros(1,1,c);Y=zeros(N,N,M);w=repmat((0:N-1),N,1);q=w';     
t =reshape(w,1,1,c);
t =bsxfun(@times,q,t);
r =reshape(q,1,1,c);
r =bsxfun(@times,w,r);
e =bsxfun(@mod,t+r,N)
for p = 1:M          
      P=p-1;    
     Y(:,:,p) = sum(X(z==P))-sum(X(z==P+M))      
end`

Comment: @Bentoy13..Instead of `e=bsxfun(@mod,t+r,N)` it is `z=bsxfun(@mod,t+r,N)` I could not get correct output as as all elements of X with `z=P` and `z=P+M` are getting added up instead of only the elements of X in each layer.

Comment: @VISHNUJMENON Thanks for the code; good thing to use `bsxfun`! Using a mask for indexing results in vectorizing the array. To keep an array, I use the (dirty) syntax `X.*(z==P)`. Then you can have the elements in Y with: `Y(:,:,p) = sum(X.*(z==P),3)-sum(X.*(z==P+M),3)`, to add along the 3rd dimension. However, with the rest of the code, it's not working properly, I get only one non-zero element... maybe there is another bug.

Comment: @Bentoy13..I could not understand the syntax given above fully..Can u post full code?.. I converted `X` into a 3D array where each layer corresponds to the input 2D matrix.Using the code I posted,I am able to get `z` as a 3D matrix in which each layer corresponds to `z` obtained as per your first solution vectorising the two inner loops..Now is there a possibility to `add` the elements of `X` in 3rd dimension(ie each layer of `X`) as per the value of corresponding element of `z ? ie z==P or z==P+M)`..Thanks again

Comment: @VISHNUJMENON For full code: just replace your line `Y(:,:,p)=...` with the one i give you in my previous comment. It does exactly what you want, ie add the elements in 3rd dimension wrt the mask.

Comment: @Bentoy13..Thanks..But I could not get the correct output..for input of a 2x2 matrix `X=[1,2;3,4]`  the correct output should be a 2x2x1 matrix which should be `Y=[-10,-2;-4,0]`..But what I am getting is `Y=[4,0;0,0]`..Please help me correct the bug..Thanks again..

Comment: @VISHNUJMENON The problem seems to come from the computation of `z`. I think the indexes are not ok...unfortunaltely, I don't have time now to work on this :(

Comment: @Bentoy13..I also think that it is due to the problem of improper indexing..Anyways thanks so much for your help..